# Jet spaces between non Hausdorff manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, jets, hausdorff-spaces, smooth-manifolds

I found it very hard to find literature about smooth manifolds that are not required to be Hausdorff. In particular I'm interested in their local properties:

1.) Are the $r$-th order jet bundles $J^r(M,N)$ well defined for non Hausdorff manifolds?
(Recall that this question includes the tangent bundle as it is $J^1(\mathbb{R},M)$ at least for Hausdorff ones.)

2.) What are the basic consequences on the 'usual' structures on smooth manifolds, if we drop the Hausdorff assertion? (Like no partition of the unity ...)

3.) Is there a book or some other comprehensive work on non Hausdorff SMOOTH manifolds?

Comment: Not that it would be necessary for it to be a good question, but I think it would be interesting for the readers if you provided some info about why / in which context you feel the need of relaxing the Hausdorff hypothesis in smooth manifold theory.

Comment: I think the example with the most practical relevance is the leaf space of a foliation. Especially the 'arrows' space of a monodromy Lie-groupoid is a non Hausdorff manifold in many cases.


Comment: (1) All the standard induced bundles make perfectly good sense for non-Hausdorff manifolds.  I don't know what you mean by your question (2), but it sounds too non-specific for this forum.  (3) Have you tried a search? 

Comment: Re: 2) - I think it is too unfocussed a question, rather than too specialised. Regarding 1), it might be profitable to consider what happens in algebraic geometry, where Hausdorffness is not available: they deal with tangent bundles etc using maps from $k[x]/(x^2)$ (if you are working over a field $k$). Synthetic differential geometry might also be of use to you. In fact, I think SDG would the best way to approach this problem.

Comment: Maybe you could also be interested in the definition of bundles and sheaves on a differentiable stack, such as the one associated to a Lie groupoid, which would perhaps avoid treating non-Hausdorffness of quotients (such as leaf spaces of foliations). On the other hand if the arrow space of your groupoid is itself non Hausdorff, I guess considering stacks will not change much...

Comment: Also, I think people who invented non commutative geometry started to look at C*-algebras instead of leaf spaces just to avoid particularly bad behaved non-Hausdorff manifolds...

Comment: I hope that I could stay in the category of smooth finite manifolds. Dealing with stacks or using SDG is something I would like to avoid, if I'm able to. At least I just need a well defined definition of jets.

Question 2 is rather vague, I know. But giving a precise list of all natural structures on finite smooth manifolds would be long. I hope that you just tell me what you know about existence of any nature structure (jet spaces, differential forms, metrics, cohomology ... )
Feel free to talk about other natural structures, too - since there seems to be no standard book out there

Comment: @Ryan Budney: Can you please give me a reference or explain in detail why dropping the Haussdorff assumption has no effect on the standard natural bundles ?

Comment: There's a standard construction of tangent bundles.  The idea is that you can reconstruct your manifold as an adjunction of open subsets of Euclidean space (this works even for non-Hausdorff manifolds).  So you can define the tangent bundle and any bundle construction provided you build the fibres in a functorial way from the tangent fibers.  See for example Conlon's textbook. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't contain any proofs, but Bourbaki's *Variétés différentiables - Fascicule de résultats* defines jet bundles (Section 12) without assuming that the underlying varieties are Hausdorff.

Comment: Ok this a reference. Unfortunately it stays not in the realm of finite dimensional smooth manifolds.